# Private 'for' loop for every thread in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

**See edit below for my preliminary solution**

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {

int counter = 0;
int i;

omp_set_num_threads(8); 

#pragma omp parallel
        { 
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            #pragma omp for private(i)
            for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                printf("id: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
                #pragma omp critical // or atomic
                counter++;
            }
        }

printf("counter %d\n", counter);

return 0;
}
```

I define the number of threads to be 8. For each of the 8 threads I would like to have a `for` loop for every individual threads that increments the variable `counter`. However, it seems that OpenMP parallelize the `for` loop:

```
i: 0 thread: 0
i: 1 thread: 0
i: 4 thread: 2
i: 6 thread: 4
i: 2 thread: 1
i: 3 thread: 1
i: 7 thread: 5
i: 8 thread: 6
i: 5 thread: 3
i: 9 thread: 7
counter 10
```

Consequently, `counter=10`, but I want `counter=80`. What can I do so that every threads performs its own `for` loop while all threads increment `counter`?

**The following code gives the desired result:**
I added another outer `for` loop that loops from 0 to the maximal number of threads. Inside this loop I can then declare my `for` loop private for each thread. Indeed, `counter=80` in this case. **Is this the optimal solution for this problem or is there a better one?**

```
int main(void) {


omp_set_num_threads(8); 

int mthreads = omp_get_max_threads();

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (n=0; n<mthreads; n++) {
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("i: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
            #pragma omp critical
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
printf("counter %d\n", counter);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple - remove the worksharing construct `for`:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    { 
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("id: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
            #pragma omp critical // or atomic
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Declaring `i` inside the control part of the `for` is part of C99 and might require that you pass the compiler an option similar to `-std=c99`. Otherwise you could simply declare `i` at the beginning of the block. Or you could declare it outside the region and make it `private`:

```
int i;

#pragma omp parallel private(i)
    { 
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("id: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
            #pragma omp critical // or atomic
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Since you are not using the value of `counter` inside the parallel region, you could also use sum reduction instead:

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:counter)
    { 
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            printf("id: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenMp has a concept for this, `reduction`. To stay with your example

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:counter)
  for (unsigned n=0; n<mthreads; n++) {
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i<10; i++) {
      printf("i: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
      counter++;
    }
  }
```

This has the advantage not to define a critical section around the increment. OpenMp collects the total of all the different incarnations of `counter` all by itself, and probably more efficiently.

This can even be formulated much simpler as

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:counter)
  for (unsigned i=0; i<mthreads*10; i++) {
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("i: %d thread: %d\n", i, id);
    counter++;
  }
```

For some compilers you probably still have to insist with a flag such as `-std=c99` that you want to declare variables within the `for` loop. The advantage with declaring variables as local as possible, you don't have to insist that they'd be private or things like that. And the easiest way is certainly to have OpenMp do the split of the `for`-loop all by itself.